# Query optimization in greenplum

Tags: sql, greenplum

I have a query

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY getdate()) AS ID, GETDATE() as time, tmp.* from 
( select RecordType, TrnYear, SUM(MonthlySales) as AnnualSales
FROM vwKPI_SalesGraphMonthly
WHERE RecordType = 'A'
GROUP BY RecordType, TrnYear

UNION ALL

SELECT RecordType, TrnYear, SUM(MonthlySales) as AnnualSales
FROM vwKPI_SalesGraphMonthly
WHERE RecordType = 'B'
GROUP BY RecordType, TrnYear

UNION ALL

SELECT RecordType, TrnYear, SUM(MonthlySales) as AnnualSales
FROM vwKPI_SalesGraphMonthly
WHERE RecordType = 'R'
GROUP BY RecordType, TrnYear

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Y', TrnYear, SUM(MonthlySales) as AnnualSales
FROM vwKPI_SalesGraphMonthly CROSS JOIN ArControl  
25 THEN FinPeriod -1 ELSE FinPeriod END)
WHERE RecordType = 'B' AND TrnMonth <=DATE_PART('month', GETDATE())
GROUP BY RecordType, TrnYear
) tmp
```

`vwKPI_SalesGraphMonthly` is another query of about 300 line.
I don't want to insert the definition of `vwKPI_SalesGraphMonthly` 4 times in this query. Is there any way to declare the definition of `vwKPI_SalesGraphMonthly` only once in the query and use it in all union.

Comment: Does Greenplum support [common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)?

Comment: yes Greenplum support CTE, in my experience performance goes down if you use CTE

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CTE is available with `set optimizer=on`.

Pivotal Query Optimizer handles queries that contain the WITH clause. The WITH clause, also known as a common table expression (CTE), generates temporary tables that exist only for the query. This example query contains a CTE.

```
WITH v AS (SELECT a, sum(b) as s FROM T where c < 10 GROUP BY a)
  SELECT *FROM  v AS v1 ,  v AS v2
  WHERE v1.a <> v2.a AND v1.s < v2.s;
```

As part of query optimization, the Pivotal Query Optimizer can push down predicates into a CTE. For example query, Pivotal Query Optimizer pushes the equality predicates to the CTE.

```
WITH v AS (SELECT a, sum(b) as s FROM T GROUP BY a)
  SELECT *
  FROM v as v1, v as v2, v as v3
  WHERE v1.a < v2.a
    AND v1.s < v3.s
    AND v1.a = 10
    AND v2.a = 20
    AND v3.a = 30;
```

Pivotal Query Optimizer can handle these types of CTEs:
CTE that defines one or multiple tables. In this query, the CTE defines two tables.

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT a, sum(b) as s FROM T 
               where c < 10 GROUP BY a),
      cte2 AS (SELECT a, s FROM cte1 where s > 1000)
  SELECT *
  FROM cte1 as v1, cte2 as v2, cte2 as v3
  WHERE v1.a < v2.a AND v1.s < v3.s;
Nested CTEs.
WITH v AS (WITH w AS (SELECT a, b FROM foo 
                      WHERE b < 5) 
           SELECT w1.a, w2.b 
           FROM w AS w1, w AS w2 
           WHERE w1.a = w2.a AND w1.a > 2)
  SELECT v1.a, v2.a, v2.b
  FROM v as v1, v as v2
  WHERE v1.a < v2.a;
```